# My Action bar menu is not display in another activity but it display in the main Activity only(i'm using Fragment and non Fragment)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

In android studio i am beginner,i learn it from the internet tutorial so i'm using navigation drawer with no action bar I create my own action bar and i'm using fragment but when it mix with without fragment only the action bar is display with out actionbar menu items except for the main activity. 
Here my .xml file below

```
<include
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="137dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here my java file below

```
    public class Grade_book extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grade_book);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_grade,menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include toolbar (The one with include tag) in .xml files of other activities also.
The layout or UI of each activity is defined by its respective .xml file and not by other activities.

Comment: i already include the toolbar in other activity,the code i show is another activity(not the main activity ) would you kindly show me the code i need it badly.